# System becomes non interactive when multiple real time threads are run on limited number of CPUs

Tags: linux, scheduling, real-time

```
Linux arch 5.5.9-arch1-2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 12 Mar 2020 23:01:33 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have been experimenting with CPUs affinity and scheduling policies and there is one thing that has surprised me. My machine has 12 cores. I have set affinity for the program to the last 2 cores only. The only thing my application does is creating multiple threads, generating some fake load and dumping the timing results. The main part of the thread function looks as follows:

```
void set_affinity_real_time_thread(void)
{
    cpu_set_t set;

    uint32_t err;

    CPU_ZERO(&set);

    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 1; i <= number_of_separated_cores; i++) { //number_of_separated_cores = 2
        CPU_SET(number_of_cpus - i, &set);
    }

    err = sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(set), &set);
    if (err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "%s line %d %s",
                __func__,
                __LINE__,
                strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


// #define NUMBER_OF_TIMING_SAMPLES 10000
// #define NUMBER_OF_FOR_LOOP_ITERATIONS 1000000
// #define BASE_SLEEP_TIME_US 20

void *real_time_thread(void *arg)
{
    const char *thread_type = "real_time";
    uint32_t thread_number = *(uint32_t *)arg;
    char thread_name[64];
    sprintf(thread_name, "%s_thread_%d", thread_type, thread_number);

    set_affinity_real_time_thread();
    set_policy_and_priotiy_real_time_thread();

    uint32_t timings[NUMBER_OF_TIMING_SAMPLES];
    memset(timings, 0, sizeof(timings));

    volatile int dummy = 0; // Used to simulate processing delay.
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;
    unsigned long processing_time;
    useconds_t sleep_time = BASE_SLEEP_TIME_US * (10 * thread_number);

    printf("%s started!\n", thread_name);

    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TIMING_SAMPLES; i++) {
        uint32_t j;

        gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);
        for (j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_FOR_LOOP_ITERATIONS; j++) {
            dummy++;
        }
        gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);

        processing_time = 1000000*end_time.tv_sec
                          + end_time.tv_usec
                          - 1000000*start_time.tv_sec
                          - start_time.tv_usec;
        if (processing_time > UINT32_MAX) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Processing time is too long!\n"
                    "Decrease number of for loop iterations\n.");
        }
        timings[i] = processing_time;

        usleep(sleep_time);
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

    dump_thread_results(thread_name, timings);

    printf("%s thread %d finished!\n", thread_type, thread_number);
}
```

I create 10 threads for tests. When I do not change the scheduling policy the behavior is what I expect. 10 threads run on 2 cores and the system remains fully interactive. However, when I set the policy to `SCHED_FIFO` in the following way:

```
void set_policy_and_priotiy_real_time_thread(void)
{
    int max_pri = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);

    struct sched_param param;
    param.sched_priority = max_pri;

    int err;
    err = sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &param);
    if (err != 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s line %d %s", __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

the system behavior gets really strange. It becomes completely non interactive during the test.
I can't input characters or move mouse cursor, the display is freezed. When the processing finishes everything gets back to normal. I do not understand this behavior. Only 2 cores are used for this processing (this is what I can see when I use conventional scheduling), there are still 10 cores left. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: can you show us how you are setting the affinity? also, can you show the definitions of the variables `dummy`, `processing_time`, `timings[]` and `sleep_time`? I assume `start_time` and `end_time` are `struct timeval` ... (just so you know where I'm going, the compiler might optimise out the `for` loop and/or there might be overflow in your `processing_time` calculation)

Comment: @MurrayJensen I have edited the question to add more code snippets. The CPU affinity is set correctly. I have realized that from times to times the system becomes interactive before the tests ends, and in such cases I can see in `htop`, that only 2 cores are used for crated threads.

Comment: Try picking a different pair of cores for your threads to run on ...

Comment: It helped! It looks like this weird behavior happens only when real time threads are run on the 2 last cores. @MurrayJensen do you know the explanation? The only thing I can think of is that some X threads are bound to these cores, but I do not know how to verify this.

Comment: I was guessing that the system is only servicing interrupts on one cpu - probably the last one - and you are chewing all cpu time on that cpu - but I thought this behaviour was not still there in current kernels hmmmm...

Comment: Can we somehow verify your hypothesis?

Comment: Probably not interrupts - see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516115/whats-the-policy-determining-which-cpu-handles-which-interrupt-in-the-linux-ker#) - your idea is probably better - run your test on a virtual console and see if the system still "freezes" ... But maybe check your IRQ affinity too ...

Comment: Puzzle solved. It is X that binds some processes to the last core. In case of non X tty the system stays fully interactive during the test.